# Strange variable type declaration

Tags: c, variable-declaration

when I had a look on the sources of opensc, especial the libpkcs11.c file, I found a type declaration combined with a function call which I just don't understand:

```
CK_RV rv, (*c_get_function_list)(CK_FUNCTION_LIST_PTR_PTR);
c_get_function_list = (CK_RV (*)(CK_FUNCTION_LIST_PTR_PTR)) sc_dlsym(mod->handle, "C_GetFunctionList");
```

I know that:

- CK_RV is a typedef for `unsigned long`
- CK_FUNCTION_LIST_PTR_PTR is a typedef for something like `**ck_function_list` where ck_function_list is a struct
- rv is a variable
- c_get_function_list is a variable

But if I split the first line and substitute the typedefs with their original values , I get something like:

```
unsigned long rv;
unsigned long (*c_get_function_list)(**ck_function_list);
```

So, what does the **(**ck_function_list)** in the second line mean ?

Thanks in advance,
Robert

Comment: Minor nitpick: I think `**ck_function_list` should be `ck_function_list**` here.

Comment: read this http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Comment: You should show the complete definition of `CK_FUNCTION_LIST_PTR_PTR` as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unsigned long (*c_get_function_list)(<param>);
```

is a function pointer to a function whose prototype is.

```
unsigned long func(<param>);
```

The pointer here is `c_get_function_list`

Answer (score 0):

`c_get_function_list` is pointer to function. When assigned, you can call the pointed function like normal function call: `c_get_function_list( param )`.